# Methods and statics: Accessing "fields"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following mongoose model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var addressDefinition = require('./addressPersistenceModel');   

var UserEntityModel = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    address: addressDefinition
});
mongoose.model('User', UserEntityModel);
```

The definition of the address is done like that:

```
module.exports = {
    street: String,
    ...
};
```

I do this for reasons of reusability.

And in my business logic I do this:

```
UserBusinessLogic.prototype.create = function(inputModel, callback) {
    var user = new UserPersistenceModel();
    user.firstname = inputModel.firstname;
    user.lastname = inputModel.lastname;
    ...

    user.save(function(error) {
        ...
        }
    });
};
```

Instead of assigning all the values from my input to the model in the business logic, I'd like to pass the input model to my model (in the constructor) like this:

```
var user = new UserPersistenceModel(inputModel);
```

There all the values from the input should be read and assigned to the "fields" of my model.

To do so I thought about methods and/or statics. As far as I understood I should use a method as I'm working on the "instance level" (I want to save ONE document), right? How could my method look? I'm not sure how to access the fields in there.

**Update**

This is how my `UserCreateInputModel` looks like:

```
var Address = require('../address');

var UserCreateInputModel = function(req) {
    this.alias = req.param('alias');
    this.email = req.param('email');
    this.firstName = req.param('firstName');
    this.lastName = req.param('lastName');
    this.password = req.param('password');
    this.address = new Address(req);
};
module.exports = UserCreateInputModel;
```

And this is how the address looks like:

```
var Address = function(req, persistenceModel) {    
    if(req !== null && req !== undefined) {
        this.city = req.param('city');
        this.country = req.param('country');
        this.state = req.param('state');
        this.street = req.param('street');
        this.zipCode = req.param('zipCode');
    }

    if(persistenceModel !== null && persistenceModel !== undefined) {
        this.city = persistenceModel.city;
        this.country = persistenceModel.country;
        this.state = persistenceModel.state;
        this.street = persistenceModel.street;
        this.zipCode = persistenceModel.zipCode;
    }
};
```

module.exports = Address;

Comment: If you pass a javascript object to a mongoose model when instantiating it, the attributes will be assigned automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the mongoose `User` model. What you have to to in your business logic:

```
// assuming you're doing a 'module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserEntityModel);' in your schema file
var UserPersistenceModel = require('./your_user_schema_file.js');

UserBusinessLogic.prototype.create = function(inputModel, callback) {

  // if your inputModel passed to this function is a javascript object like:
  // {
  //  firstName: "First",
  //  lastName: "Last",
  //  ...
  // }
  var user = new UserPersistenceModel(inputModel);
  ...

  user.save(function(error) {
    ...
  });
};
```

**UPDATED**

You're referencing your address model incorrectly.

Assuming that you have an `module.exports = mongoose.model('Address', AddressEntityModel);` line at the end of your `Adress` model, this is the way that you have to reference it in your `User` model:

```
var UserEntityModel = new Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  address: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Address' }
});
```

You don't even have to require the address model file.

Mongoose just stores the the `id` from the referenced object. So, the only attribute from the referenced address that you're able to change is the `id` (like cleaning the reference or pointing it to another address).

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that it was possible to pass objects to the constructor of the model. However I'm using one subdocument inside my model (see updated code) and it looks like this mechanism isn't working for subdocuments. Any idea?

Comment: I would like to use the address as embedded document (no ref), but keep the definition in an external file for reusability.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. In this case, you just need one mongoose Schema, since you'll not reference the address as an external mongoose Model. To do so, export your adress logic like `module.exports = { street: String, city: String, zipCode: Number }` and so on. Then, require it on the User Schema as plain Javascript, without instantiating a new Schema.

Comment: I've tried this (and updated my code in my question), but the parameters of the address are still undefined. Somehow the "auto assignment/mapping" seems not to work for embedded documents. :-(

Comment: Is the variable `addressDefinition` `undefined` after you do `var addressDefinition = require('./addressPersistenceModel');`?

Comment: addressDefinition is defined. But the "auto assignment" of the values doesn't work by passing my input model to the constructor. In my business logic I do `var user = new UserPersistenceModel(inputModel);` Now `console.log(user.firstname);` provides the first name while `console.log(user.address.street);` says `undefined`. Setting the value manually (like `user.address.street = 'My street 3';`) works without problems.

Comment: And this doesn't have to do anything with my "definition" of the address in my model. I've just tried the same without the addressdefinition in a seperate file but directly in my user schema as embedded document (like meta @ http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html) and the "auto assignment" isn't working, too. So this seems to be a general problem with embedded documents. To me it looks like this "mechanism" isn't working with embedded documents.

Comment: When are you calling `console.log(user.address.street);`, before or after you save? How does your `inputModel` looks like?

Comment: After save. The street (and all other fields of the address) is just not asigned and so it's not saved. I've updated my question. It now contains the input model(s).

Comment: Ok, but inside the `Address` constructor, if your log, let's say `req.params('street')` or `req.params('city')`, does it have any data?

Comment: Yes, it has the right data. I've logged the input model and it looks correctly. It has all needed values (firstname, lastname, but also the address including street, ...).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69403/discussion-between-rodrigo-medeiros-and-mosquito87).